# In Swift, can a function of another object be cast to a different type of object?

Tags: swift, casting

I'm following the MapKit tutorial on Ray Wenderlich's [site](https://www.raywenderlich.com/160517/mapkit-tutorial-getting-started) and I'm a little confused on what a few lines of code are saying.

Specifically under the comment //4, it appears that the developer uses a constant variable that's equal to a function of the mapView and then casts it to a type of MKMarkAnnotationView.

I've never seen anything like this but I'd like to understand it before moving on.  I understand that functions are objects too and I understand that it is possible to place a function inside a variable however in this example the developer not only places a function inside a variable, but the developer also casts it into a different type which is confusing.  Can this line of code be broken down into smaller steps to help me understand it better?

It seems the developer called on the mapView object which is of type MKMapView but was allowed to optionally cast it to a type of MKMarkerAnnotationView.

```
//4
        if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
            dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
            view = dequeuedView
        }
```

Here is the viewController's code in its entirety if needed:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //created an IBOutlet to control the mapView in interface builder
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        //initial location to zoom the map into once the app is opened.
        let initialLocation = CLLocation.init(latitude: 21.282778, longitude: -157.829444)

        centerMapOnLocation(location: initialLocation)

        mapView.delegate = self

        let artwork = Artwork.init(title: "King David Kalakaua", locationName: "Waikiki Gateway Park", discipline: "Sculpture", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: 21.283921, longitude: -157.831661))

        mapView.addAnnotation(artwork)

  }

    //when specifying a latlong to zoom into in iOS, you must also state a rectangular region for it to display a correct zoom level???
    let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000

    func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation){
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, regionRadius, regionRadius)
        mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }

}

extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        //2
        guard let annotation = annotation as? Artwork else {
            return nil
        }
        //3
        let identifier = "marker"
        var view: MKMarkerAnnotationView
        //4
        if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
            dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
            view = dequeuedView
        } else {
            //5
            view = MKMarkerAnnotationView.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            view.canShowCallout = true
            view.calloutOffset = CGPoint.init(x: -5, y: 5)
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.init(type: .detailDisclosure)
            view.markerTintColor = UIColor.green
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to read about optional casts (`as?`) and optional binding (`if let`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is optional unwrapping.
As you noticed - developer optionally casted function's result to `MKMarkerAnnotationView`. But he also used this with `if let` syntax which is optional unwrapping. This means that this code

```
dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
view = dequeuedView
```

will only be executed if cast succeeded (i.e. if cast result wasn't `nil`). Otherwise this code will be ignored.

You can also do this with `guard` statement. E.g.:

```
guard let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView 
else { // code here will be executed if casting fails. In this case you also have to return function }

dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
view = dequeuedView
```

More info [in documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

Comment: you're right, I forgot all about how as a developer you can cast the result of a function to a different type!  And MKMarkerAnnotationView does inherit from UIView similar to MapView!  Much appreciated.